# Override `this` to `window` for an import in vite

Tags: javascript, node-modules, vite

I'm using an old version of a dependency that uses `this` to refer to `window`. It attaches a variable to the window like this: `this.variable = variable`
Running `yarn vite`, I get this in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'variable')
```

Is there a way in Vite for `this` to be set to `window` so I can use this kind of dependency in my project?

Comment: No, use [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) instead.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to fork the dependency and update it, publish your fork, and use it. :-)

Comment: https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#syntax-error-type-error-happens